# How to calculate confidence intervall and z-score for a weibull distribution? (2 and 3 parameter)

Tags: confidence-interval, weibull-distribution, z-score

How can i calculate the confidence interval (CI) of a weibull distribution?

I have raw data e.g.: 3,5,7,2,11,97, 223, ...

I can calculate the mean (µ), standard deviation (SD).

But how can i calclulate the confidence intervals?

And the next question would be how can i calculate the z-score for a non-normal distribution?...

For the "easy" case of a normal distribution there are many sources...

I am looking for a equation/calculator like:

https://www.calculator.net/confidence-interval-calculator.html?size=50&mean=20.6&sd=3.2&cl=95&x=55&y=7

Other related links which i read but doens't find the answer:

- https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/Weibull3distribution.php
- https://www.real-statistics.com/other-key-distributions/weibull-distribution/three-parameter-weibull-distribution/
- http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

I am looking for the **mean and sd confidence intervals**.

Comment: You seem to be approaching this as if all distributions behaved like the Normal distribution.  That's not the case here. In particular, a Z-score is of little use. The parameters of a Weibull distribution are much more naturally expressed in terms of a *shape* and *scale,* neither of which has a nice analytical relationship with the mean and sd.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution for the details. So, please tell us what you want confidence intervals for: the distribution; its parameters; the mean and SD; or something else?

Comment: I am looking for the mean and sd confidence intervals

Comment: The answer then depends on what procedure you are using to fit the distribution.  Maximum Likelihood?  Method of Moments?  Weibull probability plots?  Something else?

Comment: I am using the Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Comment: Then I would try to make a confidence interval using profile likelihood, search this site!